# How can I setup a system to tell me if a cron job is NOT running fine?

Tags: cron, task, scheduled-tasks

This is more of an "general architecture" problem. If you have a cron job (or even a Windows scheduled task) running periodically, its somewhat simple to have it send you an email / text message that all is well, but *how* do I get informed when everything is NOT okay? Basically, if the job doesn't run at its scheduled time or Windows / linux has its own set of hangups that prevent the task from running...?

Just seeking thoughts of people who've faced this situation before and come up with interesting solutions...

Comment: Make a cron job that checks the cron job :D

Comment: Despite the humour, David, that's _not_ a bad suggestion. A single cron job can fail for any number of reasons, only one of which is the entire cron subsystem being down.

Comment: Thank you alex. David / paxdiablo - would relying on an 'external' / 3rd party cron service be a good bet... as the "cron-checker"?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Honestly, I don't think I've seen cron itself fail more than a couple of times in my 30-year career. I'm not sure I'd use a lot of effort on something that's so unlikely. But, if you really want peace of mind, use a separate cron _job_ to ensure the other jobs are running, and also have a job send a message of some sort to another machine, perhaps using its cron (meta-cron) to check if the message hasn't arrived. Just keep in mind that will give you false positives for other situations (like the network being down). And do you want a meta-meta-cron to keep an eye on it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way I've done it in the past is to simply put at the top of each script (say, `checkUsers.sh`):

```
touch /tmp/lastrun/checkUsers.sh
```

then have another job that runs periodically that uses `find` to locate all those "marker" files in `tmp/lastrun` that are older than a day.

You can fiddle with the timings, having `/tmp/lastrun/hour/` and `tmp/lastrun/day/` to separate jobs that have different schedules.

Note that this won't catch scripts that have *never* run since they will never create the initial file for `find`-ing. To alleviate that, you can either:

- create that file manually when creating the cron job (won't handle situations where someone inadvertently deletes the marker file); or
- maintain a list of required marker files somewhere so that you can detect when they're missing as well as outdated.

And, if your cron job is not a script, put the `touch` directly into `crontab`:

```
0 4 * * * ( touch /tmp/lastrun/daily/checkUsers ; /usr/bin/checkUsers )
```

It's a lot easier to validate a simple `find` script than to validate every one of your `cron` jobs.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but if one cron fails, would it be likely they all would (if it were a hardware or software error) ?

Comment: Not necessarily, the problem may be with the line in the crontab file or it may be permissions on the script. If there's a fault with cron itself, yes. Then you can put it in your login script (or `/etc/profile` or mount an NFS filesystem elsewhere touching files on that, hoping that its cron will be running for checks). But, if `cron` itself is not working, there's few other options for automating a check. At some point, you have to trust that _one_ layer of software will function okay :-) I didn't say it was foolproof - all it does is make it easier to detect a fault.

Comment: Interesting approach... not _exactly_ what I was looking for... (a more complete solution, possibly using external systems as well)